# Python universal install with conda

Tags: python, conda, apple-m1

I recently got a new M1 MacBook and have been trying to get my Python Dev environment setup. I’m new to conda (previously used virtualenv) and I’m wondering if there’s a way to use the Python 3.9.4 universal2 install. 3.9.2 is the highest version listed, and I can’t see how to distinguish it from the Intel/ARM installations, but running platform.machine() outputs x86_64, so it seems I have the Intel install by default. Any way to manage this?

Comment: Have you tried [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge)? You won’t have 3.9 in **base**, but one shouldn’t really work in **base** anyway. You can always make new envs with what you need.

Comment: Actually, just saw the footnotes say Miniforge installs 3.9 for `arm64` by default, so you would have it in **base**.

Comment: I hadn't tried that yet, for some reason i assumed miniforge came with more overhead specifically for data science use, but I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** [Come here](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual)
Scroll down to the line Anaconda 2019.03 for macOS Installer.

You need to know your Python version. To do this, write in the terminal

[image: pv]

And select Command Line Installer

**Step 2:** installing via command line
After the installation is complete, go to the terminal.

If you have Python 3.7, then run:

bash ~ / Downloads / Anaconda3–2019.03-MacOSX-x86_64.sh

For Python 2.7:

bash ~ / Downloads / Anaconda2–2019.03-MacOSX-x86_64.sh

Attention: if you downloaded Anaconda not in the Downloads folder, then in the commands you need to change the path to the distribution kit.

Review the license agreement and press Enter. Finally, after a million Enter hits, type yes if you accept the license agreement.

(If you do not accept the agreement in time, then this clue will constantly catch your eye)

[image: ist]

if you are satisfied with the installation path, then press Enter. You can change the location or abort the installation by pressing CTRL-C.

Then you will be asked: Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3 by running conda init? Write yes, of course.

When the installation is complete, close a terminal window and open a new one - this will take effect your changes. Want to make sure everything works? Type conda list and see what happens. If everything works, you will see something like this:
[image: res]

**If everything works, then congratulations! Now you can use Anaconda, Jupyter Notebooks, Spyder and other useful things.**

Comment: Sorry if I didn’t clarify my problem more. I have conda working fine, the problem is the specific Python versions available seem to be only those built for Intel, even though there are universal installations available on the Python downloads page. The universal installation is what I’m trying to figure out how to install with conda so that it can work with my conda environments.